# Using GPL library in our software

Tags: licensing, gpl, libraries, third-party-libraries

Currently we're starting to work on a project for which we're going to need image processing libraries. The problem is some of the libraries are GPL licensed.

I'm reading through GPL licence and quite a lot of other ones (FreeImage public licence etc..) and I'm a bit confused of all the long text. So I'll ask bluntly:

Is it possible to use a GPL licenced library in our commercial product (not modifying the code, just building the library and using it in our product (as a DLL)) without releasing the source code of our product?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use GPL software in a commercial application](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/47032/can-i-use-gpl-software-in-a-commercial-application) and of [Call GPL software from non-GPL software](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110380/call-gpl-software-from-non-gpl-software)

Comment: I've removed the bit about other license types as there are dozens of various open source licenses.  Stack exchange Q&A works best when there is only one *right* answer for the question.  Having a question that allows for one person to answer about Apache, and another GPL, and another MSPL makes for scattering of information and reduces the usefulness of the question and answer.

Comment: You probably should make your software GPL too, but you need to **ask your lawyer**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Don't distribute

The GPL is primarily about distribution of your software (what they call "conveyance").  If you *only use your app and the GPL library in-house,* the GPL does not consider this *conveyance,* and the copyleft provision is not triggered.  You therefore don't need to make your program open-source.

#### Communicate at arms length

If your program *does not depend on the GPL library or application for its proper functioning,* and you *communicate at  arms length* with it through spawning a separate process, pipes or something similar rather than linking the library in your application directly, then the GPL considers your program a *separate application* (instead of a *derived work*), and you don't need to make your program open-source.

Comment: 2nd point is not strictly true. Communicating with a GPL program may legally be considered as "linking" to it... (it really depends if the protocol is used by several applications or not)

Comment: The primary idea is that your program does not depend on the library (that bit about "derived works").  But I do agree it's a gray area (the FSF says as much).  Not really sure what several other applications have to do with anything.

Comment: ok, can't use GPL then. We're making a program that controls a robot taking pictures of an object, the program then processes them (contrast, balance, masking, etc...) on the fly and makes several types of presentations/collections of them....